# Liferay gives "ERROR [PortletRequestProcessor:377] Forward does not exist" while installing new portlet

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I try to install a new portlet from `plugins installation` page and I get this

```
ERROR [PortletRequestProcessor:377] Forward does not exist
```

And plugin is not installed. What should this be about?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was building a hook extending "BaseStrutsPortletAction". In my custom class I had to override the render method and set it like:

```
@Override
   public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction,
         PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
         RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(null, portletConfig,
                renderRequest, renderResponse);
   }
```